# Showing Tab Bar on unlinked View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uinavigationbar

I'm currently making an app which has 4 pages accessible via a tab bar, no problems there. However I have a button on one of the viewcontrollers (lets say A) that opens up another viewcontroller (B). B opens fine, the problem I have now is that the tab bar disappears as it isn't linked to the tab bar controller. Also creating a back button on B to A hasn't helped as the tab bar has gone from A where it usually is.

How would I get the tab bar to show on every viewcontroller I create without there needing to be an icon for every viewcontroller?

Comment: If you embed A in a navigation controller, and push to B, then the tab bar will still be visible (I presume that you're modally presenting B now).

Comment: @rdelmar thanks, yes B is opened via a button with modal. A is in the nav bar, B only accessible via A. But when the button is pressed, B opens but covers the whole iPhone screen including the nav bar. Read somewhere about wrapping?

Comment: You mean tab bar, right? That's the way modal views work, they cover the whole view. If you don't want that, then use a navigation controller and a push instead like I suggested. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: @rdelmar no particular reason, I'm just having to teach myself this (so sorry if im sounding stupid) for my dissertation and using a tab bar seemed to be what I was after; which was to have links to other pages at the bottom of screen with icons and pretty easy to set up by dragging and connecting view controllers to the tab bar controller

Comment: I'm not saying to go without the tab bar controller. You just make the root view controller of one of the tabs a navigation controller with A being its root view controller. Then you can use a push to go to B and still see your tab bar.

Comment: @rdelmar ok I think I've got you now, using the navigation bar adds the back button to be able to go from B to A therefore making sure the tab bar is back visible on A. So by pushing to go from A to B this means the tab bar will still be visible on B and not covered by the modal which is more like a pop up type view? (if ive understood this correctly?)